# Angular JS rendering code?

Tags: angularjs

I use old version Angular JS 1.5.
When backend returns views where was integrated Angular JS, it rendering with showing source code. So, awhile I can see Angular JS code, after it is rendered.

How to fix it? I tried `ng-cloak`. But it does not work for me

Comment: views with integrated Angular JS functions? can you share your code.

Comment: It means, there is any error in console? Or angular file was not loaded succesfully

Comment: I fixed question